# SQL Distinct with multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, ansi-sql, google-bigquery

I want to produce a table output as per the [SampleData Table & Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcus2.jpg). My SQL Query is as follows but it is not giving me the right result for last three columns

```
SELECT
  UserLogin,
  COUNT(DISTINCT consumerID) AS TotalUniqueconsumerIDs,  
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN ActivitiesCompleted > 0 AND QuizCompleted <= 0 THEN consumerID END)) AS YesActivityNoQuiz,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN ActivitiesCompleted <= 0 AND QuizCompleted > 0 THEN consumerID END)) AS NoActivityYesQuiz,  
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN ActivitiesCompleted >= 1 AND QuizCompleted >= 1 THEN consumerID END)) AS YesActivityYesQuiz
FROM
  TableName
GROUP BY
  UserLogin
```

[image: SampleData Table & Output]

Any help is highly appreciated.

---

More info:

Perhaps I wasn't clear above so providing more info here:

I created another sample table with just data of 1 UserLogin which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAN6B.jpg) and if I pivot this sample data set externally in Excel I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY5fQ.jpg)

As you can see that this pivot screenshot both of the consumerID in this table has more than 1 ActivitiesCompleted as well as 1 QuizCompleted.

The SQL Output based on my query above looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhJLq.jpg)

However, based on Pivot screenshot, I am expecting 1 in YesActivityYesQuiz column and zero in YesActivityNoQuiz & NoActivityYesQuiz

---

Sample Data:

```
Date,UserLogin,consumerID,ActivitiesCompleted,QuizCompleted
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,1
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,2,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerA,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerB,0,1
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerB,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerB,2,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerB,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerB,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerB,1,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerB,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerB,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerB,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerB,0,0
6/8/2018,aasufhar,consumerB,0,0
```

Comment: can you post your current output, so that we can compare what you are getting and what is required.

Comment: i think your query is correct! what makes you think it returns wrong result? it looks correct to me.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I edited my question and provided more info

Comment: images really hide your real data so it is hard to judge what is wrong here. as I said based on logic you explain - your query looks correct. I recommend you to provide example of data in plain text so we can help you further.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I updated the question with Sample data

Comment: You said you expect `1 in YesActivityYesQuiz column and zero in YesActivityNoQuiz & NoActivityYesQuiz` - while I see `2 in  YesActivityYesQuiz` because both A and B have and ActivityCompleted and Quiz Completed. Clarify please!

Comment: I want to count consumerID under YesActivityYesQuiz if that consumerID has done both. If a consumerID has only completed Activity then want to count that under YesActivityNoQuiz. I need to know how many consumerID do either activity, either quiz or both. I hope it makes sense?

Comment: so based on your example both consumerA and consumerB qualified to be counted in YesActivityYesQuiz! so it should be `2` - not `1`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Sorry my bad, yes it should be 2 but still the query is not giving the right result

Comment: have you tried update in my answer?? :o) it produces result that is expected

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I tried the updated query and it works perfect. I tried to modify it and include the 4th scenario to which is NoActivityNoQuiz so if I sum-up all 4 columns it should be equal to TotalUniqueconsumerIDs but it's not working :(

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I used COUNT(DISTINCT IF(ActivitiesCompleted IS NULL OR ActivitiesCompleted = 0 AND QuizCompleted IS NULL OR QuizCompleted = 0, consumerID, NULL)) AS NoActivityNoQuiz

Comment: see one more / last update in my answer. if it helped (which looks like it is ) please accept and vote on it. if more question(s) - post new one and I (we) will be happy to help

Comment: The 4th column calculation worked for some cases for some records it is not accurate. I am running this on a large database.

Comment: see my previous comment :o) it still apply - the logic and examples you supplied are all addressed. you most likely is missing something in your logic so I would recommend you to identify those edge cases and ask/post new question!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thank you so much for your help. Highly appreciated.

Comment: @MohitJain Could you [accept Mikhail answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), please?

Answer (score 2):

The query in question seems to be correct to me (at least it returns what is shown in expected result)

Still, I can propose less verbose version of it (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT UserLogin, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT consumerID) AS TotalUniqueconsumerIDs,  
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(ActivitiesCompleted > 0 AND QuizCompleted <= 0, consumerID, NULL)) AS YesActivityNoQuiz,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(ActivitiesCompleted <= 0 AND QuizCompleted > 0, consumerID, NULL)) AS NoActivityYesQuiz,  
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(ActivitiesCompleted >= 1 AND QuizCompleted >= 1, consumerID, NULL)) AS YesActivityYesQuiz
FROM TableName
GROUP BY UserLogin
```

> Updated query based on recent example/explanation from OP

```
#standardSQL
SELECT UserLogin, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT consumerID) AS TotalUniqueconsumerIDs,  
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(ActivitiesCompleted > 0 AND QuizCompleted <= 0, consumerID, NULL)) AS YesActivityNoQuiz,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(ActivitiesCompleted <= 0 AND QuizCompleted > 0, consumerID, NULL)) AS NoActivityYesQuiz,  
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(ActivitiesCompleted >= 1 AND QuizCompleted >= 1, consumerID, NULL)) AS YesActivityYesQuiz,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(ActivitiesCompleted <= 0 AND QuizCompleted <= 0, consumerID, NULL)) AS NoActivityNoQuiz
FROM (
  SELECT UserLogin,consumerID,
    SUM(ActivitiesCompleted) ActivitiesCompleted,
    SUM(QuizCompleted) QuizCompleted
  FROM TableName
  GROUP BY UserLogin,consumerID
)
GROUP BY UserLogin
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want `max()`:

```
SELECT UserLogin, COUNT(DISTINCT consumerID) AS TotalUniqueconsumerIDs,  
       MAX(CASE WHEN ActivitiesCompleted > 0 AND QuizCompleted <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS YesActivityNoQuiz,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ActivitiesCompleted <= 0 AND QuizCompleted > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoActivityYesQuiz,  
       MAX(CASE WHEN ActivitiesCompleted >= 1 AND QuizCompleted >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS YesActivityYesQuiz
FROM TableName
GROUP BY UserLogin;
```

Comment: Ha, you edited and answered it before I could get my little try written.  Magic!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include  ActivitiesCompleted in your group by clause because you are using that in your case statement. Its not throwing you error?

```
SELECT
  UserLogin,
  COUNT(DISTINCT consumerID) AS TotalUniqueconsumerIDs,  
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN ActivitiesCompleted > 0 AND QuizCompleted <= 0 THEN consumerID END)) AS YesActivityNoQuiz,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN ActivitiesCompleted <= 0 AND QuizCompleted > 0 THEN consumerID END)) AS NoActivityYesQuiz,  
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN ActivitiesCompleted >= 1 AND QuizCompleted >= 1 THEN consumerID END)) AS YesActivityYesQuiz
FROM
  TableName
GROUP BY
  UserLogin,ActivitiesCompleted
```